# Consequences if linesman interferes with play?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey

During the 2014 Russian Olympics, the United States faced Canada in hockey.  After a period of pressing on the US goal, the puck was cleared to the side. The linesman got in the way of a Canadian player, and the puck, bouncing off the boards, nearly went into the Canadian net.

Linesmen interfere with the play quite often, but are there any consequences if done so accidentally or purposefully?

Comment: Occasionally it also happens that referee might cause an injury of a player - example: [Tomas Tatar Injured after Collision with Ref](http://www.theredwingsfeed.com/tomas-tatar-injured-collision-ref/#).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only rule in the [NHL Rulebook](http://www.nhl.com/ice/page.htm?id=26489) that I could find addressing this situation is that a goal is disallowed if it goes in directly off of an official.

> 78.5 Disallowed Goals – Apparent goals shall be disallowed by the Referee and the appropriate announcement made by the Public Address
>   Announcer for the following reasons:
>
> (iii)  When the puck has deflected directly into the net off an
>   official.

Based on my understanding (but no explicit mention in the rulebook), otherwise the officials are "in play" and no particular exception exists for stopping play due to linesmen or referees obstructing play.  Clearly they are instructed to avoid doing so whenever possible, but if they're unable to avoid the play, the play stands (unless a goal goes off of an official).

It goes without saying that this only applies to NHL games and other games which take place under NHL rules.

Comment: This is right and a good answer.  But what happens to the linesmen who interferes?  He gets a few extra beers after the game from the home team!

Comment: @Coach-D Haha... I'd be very curious myself to know if they keep track of these things and discipline linesmen who do interfere.

Comment: I don't think it is an NHL issue.  Very big issue at club level.

Answer (score 2):

Under IIHF Rules, the following applies:

> RULE 73 – PUCK STRIKING AN ON-ICE OFFICIAL
>
> i.   Game action will not be stopped because the puck touches an
>   on-ice  official during the regular course of play except when:
>
> 1. The puck enters the goal net as a result of that contact;
> 2. The puck goes out of play as a result of that contact;
> 3. An on-ice official is injured.
>
> ii.   If  the  attacking  team  scores  a  goal  because  the  puck 
>   deflects  or bounces directly off an on-ice official, the goal will
>   not be allowed and  the ensuing  faceoff  will  take  place  at  the 
>   nearest  faceoff  spot  to   where the puck made contact with the
>   on-ice official.
>
> iii.  If the puck hits an on-ice official and is subsequently put into
>   the goal  net in any legal manner, the goal will be allowed.
>
> iv.   If the puck leaves the playing area after hitting an on-ice
>   official in the neutral zone, the ensuing faceoff will take place at
>   the faceoff spot in  the neutral zone nearest to where the puck made
>   contact with the  on-ice official.
>
> v.    If  the  puck  leaves  the  playing  area  after  hitting  an 
>   on-ice  official in either end zone, the ensuing faceoff will take
>   place at the faceoff spot in  the  end  zone  nearest  to  where  the 
>   puck  made  contact  with  the on-ice official.

Should the interference be intentional, the league will probably take action against the linesman.